# How to get form data when HTTP method is PATCH in Phalcon 1.3.x?

Tags: php, http, phalcon

I tested to get form data when HTTP method is PATCH in phalcon 1.3.x. after read manual and source code, can make sure the specified version of phalcon doesn't provide `getPatch()` in `Phalcon\Http\Request`.

I tried `$this->request->getPut()` or `$this->request->getPost()`, but it doesn't work. It always returns empty array.

How to get form data when HTTP method is PATCH in phalcon 1.3.x?

Comment: https://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/20795/how-to-use-http-method-patch

Answer (score 0):

Found nothing solution by google, so I extend phalcon request and implemented `getPatch()` and `hasPatch()` methods

Usage:

```
// get all patch data...
$params = $this->request->getPatch(); 

// try to get username from patch data
$name = $this->request->getPatch('username');   

// try to get and format price
$price = $this->request->getPatch('price', 'float!');
```

Before use it, injected new Request class first.

```
$di->set('request', function() {
    return new \Request();
}, true);
```

The codes on Github:

https://github.com/baohanddd/phalcon-request-with-patch

Answer (score 0):

Use $this->request->getPut() it works in 4.0 and need HTTP HEADER

Content-Type

In my variant application/json

[Link to chat](http://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/20795/how-to-use-http-method-patch)